# Wildcard queries in field name

Tags: elasticsearch

I can use simple wildcard query like this:

```
"wildcard" : { "user" : "ki*y" }
```

but if i want to use wildcard in field, then what?
How shoud look valid query for this:

```
"wildcard" : { "base/*" : "value" }
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) which allows both field names wildcards and query text wildcards.

Something around these lines:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "base*"
      ],
      "query": "ki*y"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For future visitors trying to figure out how to do this through Kibana or using the simplified syntax, the trick is to escape the wildcard -- `base/\*:value` works.

Comment: adding quotes may help as well :P

Comment: In Kibana, using the Kibana Query Language (KQL), it's as simple as `base*:value`