# Range query on multiple fields with pattern matching

Tags: elasticsearch, range

I want to execute a range query on multi fields with a pattern like:

```
GET /testindex/testtype/_search
{
   "query": {
      "range": {
         "a*": {
            "gt": 14
         }
     }
   }
}
```

I set a* in range query field name to do this query on all fields that start with 'a'.
how can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433032/wildcard-queries-in-field-I saw this. But I don't think it supports the range query. You can define all the fields one by one using a filter if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by using the [query string query syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax), like this:

```
GET /testindex/testtype/_search?q=a\*:{14 TO *}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Is there an error or you don't get any documents? Can you show one document that should match?