# How to write query with nested wildcard path in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

my sample document looks like:

> ```
> [{ 
> "id":"1234567", 
> "nodes":{
>   "2":{
>       "meta":{
>           "data":{
>            "cid":"dfr34343"
>            }
>         }
>     },
>   "5":{
>       "meta":{
>           "data":{
>            "cid":"9m9mei9"
>            }
>         }
>     },    
>  }
> },
> { 
> "id":"934343", 
> "nodes":{
>   "1":{
>       "meta":{
>           "data":{
>            "cid":"3244324ffds"
>            }
>         }
>     },
>   "3":{
>       "meta":{
>           "data":{
>            "cid":"nidsf99dff"
>            }
>         }
>     },    
>  }
> }]
> ```
>
> based on cid value i need to get the regarding document. I am new to elasticsearch query. I tried multiple ways but failed to retrieve data for this type of documents.

Comment: a) it would help if you share your mappings, if any; b) what does "wildcard" mean? You want to get documents by `cid` values?

Comment: inside nodes "1","3" are not static. so to overcome this we need to use wildcard i think.

Comment: you can try query string query, as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31433032/493928